# CollectionView does not contain CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, collectionview

I am using `Xcode7.3.1` . I added `CollectionView` from object library to `xib` file then i can’t find `CollectionViewCell` under `CollectionView`.Here attached the screenshot.This screenshot displays `CollectionView` only contain `CollectionViewFlowLayout`.Please help me how to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: you can just drag and drop a CollectionViewCell into the CollectionView. Have you tried this?

Comment: yes tried it.But i cant get it.

Comment: are you seeing the cell in the collection view?

Comment: can you change the number of items? http://imgur.com/a/nsq79

Comment: @dirtydanee I cant see that option(items)

Comment: what can you see?

Comment: delete it and again try to drag collectionview

Comment: You can not add prototype cell in XIB file, you need to use StoryBoard to add prototype cell inside collection view.

Answer (score 2):

Prototypes Cells (`UITableviewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell`) are only available in storyboard.

If you want to use the xib for custom cell, create separate xib for each prototype cell. Assign custom class and Identifier to that cell.

Now, you need to register that custom xib to use it in Collection View.

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MediaCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MediaCollectionViewCell"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily drag and drop from file inspector [image]

Or you can create custom xib cell